# Getting an end date from start date on the condition that the time difference in minutes is divisible by 10 in r

Tags: r

I am trying to solve some mystery puzzle to identify some thief using some df as is shown below. I have been able to narrow the search down using some set criteria except the last one

```
library(tidyr)
df1<- tidyr::separate(suspect_times, Time.Spotted, c("date", "time"), sep = " ")
```

Name

Occupation

date

time

Mary Martin actress 2018-01-29  12:41:00
Woody Allen director    2018-07-23  04:42:30
Lou Rawls   singer  2018-02-01  10:18:10
Lee Trevino PGA golfer  2018-12-20  03:46:00
Richard Pryor   actor   2018-03-21  18:21:20
Bette Midler    actress 2018-07-13  23:15:10
Treat Williams  actor   2018-12-23  05:53:10
Georges Seurat  painter 2018-07-15  10:27:00
Charles Ringling    formed Ringling Bros circus 2018-03-24  11:07:40
Julie Harris    actress 2018-11-14  19:09:10

### subsetting the time from midday to midnight to exclude any hour in the AM segment

```
library(lubridate)
df1[df1$time >= "12-00-00" & df1$time <= "23-59-59", ]

## Subsetting the date to fall within some defined date as shown
df1[df1$date >= "2018-10-18" & df1$date <= "2018-11-22", ]

## converting the dates in weekdays

df2 <- df1 ##replicating df1
df2$date <- strftime(df2$date, "%A") ##converting dates to weekdays
df2  ##Print converted data
```

Name

Occupation

date

time

Mary Martin actress Monday  12:41:00
Woody Allen director    Monday  04:42:30
Lou Rawls   singer  Thursday    10:18:10
Lee Trevino PGA golfer  Thursday    03:46:00
Richard Pryor   actor   Wednesday   18:21:20
Bette Midler    actress Friday  23:15:10
Treat Williams  actor   Sunday  05:53:10
Georges Seurat  painter Sunday  10:27:00
Charles Ringling    formed Ringling Bros circus Saturday    11:07:40
Julie Harris    actress Wednesday   19:09:10

##deleting the rows containing Tuesdays and Thursdays to narrow the search with the exclusion of these days

```
df3<-df2[!(df2$date=="Tuesday" | df2$date=="Thursday"),]
df3
```

Name

Occupation

date

time

88  Mary Todd Lincoln   First Lady of the United States Wednesday   20:39:30
89  Archie Moore    champion boxer  Friday  00:24:10
90  Dick Van Dyke   actor   Friday  09:15:20
91  Christopher Plummer actor   Monday  13:23:50
92  John Davidson   actor   Sunday  18:52:20
93  Ted Nugent  singer  Sunday  03:54:10
94  Nostradamus astrologer  Saturday    15:29:50
95  James Doolittle World War II aviator    Wednesday   11:40:30
96  Morey Amsterdam actor   Wednesday   05:27:10
97  Don Hewitt  TV producer Monday  11:11:20

I am now stuck here: getting an end date given that the start data is 1970 midnight and the time difference in minutes is divisible by 10- such that I can single out a particular person

Comment: Please share data in reproducible format. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @PeaceWang here is a subset of my dataframe
structure(list(Name = c("Mary Martin", "Woody Allen"), Occupation = c("actress", 
"director"), date = c("Monday", "Monday"), time = c("12:41:00", 
"04:42:30")), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))